# how to insert Embedded object in mongodb using Mvc core

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, nosql, crud

I am trying to insert and update and delete (CRUD) an embedded object into existing Monogodb document, 
assuming adding multiple addresses for a customer,

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("52ffc33cd85242f436000001"),
   "contact": "987654321",
   "dob": "01-01-1991",
   "name": "Tom Benzamin",
   "address": [
      {
         "building": "22 A, Indiana Apt",
         "pincode": 123456,
         "city": "Los Angeles",
         "state": "California"
      },
      {
         "building": "170 A, Acropolis Apt",
         "pincode": 456789,
         "city": "Chicago",
         "state": "Illinois"
      }
   ]
}
```

I can do it using command line (adding multiple address) , but through mvc core   and I can only  insert single address while inserting the document using InserOne, also I can update it using ReplaceOne , but I can add the second or third address.

here is my c# class and Interface (Service)

```
public class Customer
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("contact")]
        [Required]
        public string Contact { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("dob")]
        [Required]
        public string Dob { get; set; }


        [BsonElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }


        public Addresses Address { get; set; }



    }
        public class Addresses
        {
            public string Building { get; set; }
            public string Pincode { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string State { get; set; }

        }



}
```

and the service

```
 public Customer Create(Customer c)
{
  customers.InsertOne(c);
  return c;
}

 public void Update(string id, Customer c)
 { 
    customers.ReplaceOne(cutomer => cutomer.Id == id, c);
 }
```

Comment: Please include your code.  I assume it is C#?

Comment: @barrypicker I have added the class, any idea?

Comment: 2 issues - first, property 'Id' should be '_id' instead.  Secondly, you have property 'Address' as type 'Addresses' and class 'Addresses' is not a list.  Try `public List<Addresses> Address { get; set; }` instead.

Comment: @barrypicker why I should define them as List? I can add the address object through mongodb commands without any issue. I guess it should be same.

Comment: @ahmed - your example JSON shows an array of addresses, therefore the C# model's corresponding type would be List<Addresses>.